# mplab error: Executable code and data must be defined in an appropriate section

Tags: microcontroller, mplabx

I'm  beginner to Mplab and microController programing.i'm following a pic book .basically my program is a led turn on and off program .I'm using `mplabx-v2.10` .this is not my complete code.however the error comes from line

```
BSF STATUS, 5
```

my code

```
STATUS EQU 03H
TRISA EQU 85H
PORTA EQU 05H

    BSF STATUS, 5

    END
```

the error is

```
Error[152]   C:\USERS\MADHAWAX\MPLABXPROJECTS\P-STAR1.X\NEWASMTEMPLATE1.ASM 6 : Executable code and data must be defined in an appropriate section
```

[a snapshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sG3Uz.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to separate the data and code with appropriate keywords. So, for example, you start off with some declaration of the PIC type and any included files:

```
; beginning of source
list    p=16F684
#include <p16F684.inc>
```

Next, you can declare variables in a data section (this is just a generic example):

```
    ; declaring variables
GENVAR  UDATA           ; general variables
myvar1  res 1       ; one byte
myvar2  res 2       ; two bytes
```

Normally, you then start the code section, using the keyword `CODE`, and add a goto from the reset vector (where the processor starts executing):

```
    ; start of code (reset vector)
RESET   CODE    0x0000      ; processor reset vector
    goto    start
```

Then, you declare any further CODE sections, for example:

```
    ; main program
MAIN    CODE

start
    ; e.g. configure ports
    banksel TRISA       ; configure PORTA as all o/p
    clrf    TRISA

    ; main loop
main_loop
    ; do stuff
    ;    "

    ; repeat forever
    goto    main_loop

    ; mandatory terminator
    END
```

I think your problem is that you have started writing code without declaring a `CODE` section.

**EDIT** Just fixing your code by adding the `CODE` keyword and the initial jump from the reset vector compiles fine:

[image: asm]

You also need to make sure you respect the necessary indents/initial spaces in code lines so that they are not mistaken for labels. Your first block of code (under MAIN) was not indented, so also caused errors.

Comment: tnx.my assemble code i taken from a book is here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzmWcy_weZw2V1NDdFpaODk0TlU/view?usp=sharing
can you show me how it should be corrected

Comment: @FastSnail Ok, just this once - see updated answer.

Comment: ok i got it.tnx